# How can I design small getter-based classes without multiple execution?

Tags: c#

I like to write many small getter properties that describe exactly what they mean.

However this can lead to repeated, expensive calculations.

Every way I know to avoid this makes the code less readable.

A pseudocode example:

```
ctor(decimal grossAmount, taxRateCalculator, itemCategory)
{
   // store the ctor args as member variables
}

public decimal GrossAmount { get { return _grossAmount, } }

private decimal TaxRate { get { return _taxRateCalculater.GetTaxRateFor(_itemCategory); } } // expensive calculation

public decimal TaxAmount { get { return GrossAmount * TaxRate; } }

public decimal NetAmount { get { return GrossAmount - TaxAmount; } }
```

In this example it is very obvious what each of the properties do because they are simple accessors. TaxRate has been refactored into its own property so that it too, is obvious what it does. If the _taxRateCalculator operation is very expensive, how can I avoid repeated execution without junking up the code?

In my real scenario I might have ten fields that would need to be treated this way, so ten sets of _backing or Lazy fields would be ugly.

Comment: Why do you consider 10 sets of _backing fields 'ugly'? If it makes the code more efficient and is laid out in a readable manner I don't see the problem. You can wrap them in regions if they really offend you!

Comment: how about doing this calculation in the cTor ?

Comment: if the tax rate doesn't have to be calculated each time, why don't you store the taxrate in a local field then? If it's `null` (or some other condition), calculate it; otherwise take the local field.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but properties are not advised for complex or time-consuming operations.  Instead, use a method.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx for such an operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profile. Find out where the application is spending most of the time, and you'll have places to improve. Focus on the worst offenders, there's no point in performance optimizing something unless it has significant impact on the user experience.

When you identify the hotspots, you've got a decision to make - is the optimization worth the costs? If it is, go ahead. Having a backing field to store an expensive calculation is quite a standard way of avoiding repeated expensive calculations. Just make sure to only apply it where it matters, to keep the code simple.

This really is a common practice, and as long as you make sure you're consistent (e.g. if some change could change the tax rate, you'd want to invalidate the stored value to make sure it gets recalculated), you're going to be fine. Just make sure you're fixing a real performance problem, rather than just going after some performance ideal =)

Comment: I'd rather something better but I think that yes, you should write the code as nicely as possible with no regard to performance, and then go back and fix the one or two places where it actually matters (using one of the other methods from the other answers). That way you end up with nice, fast-ish code. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Cache the value

```
private decimal? _taxRate = null;
...
private decimal TaxRate
{
    get
    {
        if (!this._taxRate.HasValue) {
           this._taxRate = _taxRateCalculator.GetTaxRateFor(_itemCategory);
        }
        return this._taxRate.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a method which will recalculate your values every time you call here.

The advatage of this solution is

- you can recalculate your Properties manually
- you can implement some sort of Eventlistner which could easy call your recalculation anytime something happends

.

```
  ctor(decimal grossAmount, taxRateCalculator, itemCategory)
    {
      // store the ctor args as member variables
      recalculate();
    }

    public decimal GrossAmount { get; private set; }

    public decimal TaxAmount { get; private set; }

    public decimal NetAmount { get; private set; }

    public void recalculate();
    {
       // expensive calculation
       var _taxRate = _taxRateCalculater.GetTaxRateFor(_itemCategory);

       GrossAmount = grossAmount;
       TaxAmount = GrossAmount * _taxRate ;
       NetAmount = GrossAmount - _taxRate;
    }
```

Comment: You could eliminate the fields completely here and just have private setters.

Comment: @WiiMaxx following @James advice you the could also remove the `TaxRate` property

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there is a way. You want to cache data without a cache. You could build caching functionality into your `GetTaxRateFor(…)` Method, but I doubt that this is the only expensive method you call.

So the shortest way would be a BackingField. What I usually do is this:

```
private decimal? _backingField;
public decimal Property { get { return _backingField ?? (_backingField = expensiveMethode()).Value; } }
```